# Can an infinite set be transitive, irreflexive, total, and have an upper and lower bound?

Tags: logic, infinity

I need an infinite structure that can be put into an order with the following properties:

The order must...
be transitive,
be irreflexive,
be total (i.e., every two things share some sort of relation),
have an upper bound,
have a lower bound,
be such that every member with a successor has an immediate successor,
be such that every member with a predecessor has an immediate predecessor.

I'm at a loss. I don't know much about infinity, but I would naively think that these conditions force finiteness. However, my instructor told us that it can be proven for polyadic logic that if a finite set of any size can satisfy a schema (say, one that spells out the above conditions), then an infinite set can also satisfy that schema.

Is there a structure that satisfies these conditions? I would think something that looked like this might work: $\lbrace p,p+1,...,q-1,q \rbrace$, where $q$ is the upper bound; $p$ is the lower bound; $\lbrace p,p+1,... \rbrace$ is an infinitely ascending chain; $\lbrace ...,q-1,q \rbrace$ is an infinitely descending chain; and every member of $\lbrace...,q-1,q \rbrace$ is greater than every member of $\lbrace p,p+1,... \rbrace$. I know that an well-ordered series does not contain an infinitely descending chain, but perhaps the descending chain in the example could be isomorphic to a wellordered series with a starting point.

Comment: Take $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$, and replace each point with a copy of $\mathbb Z$. The simplest example is $\mathbb N$ followed by a copy of the negative integers.

Comment: @Andres: What would be the minimal element?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, yes, in the draft in my mind, I wrote "replace $0$ with a copy of $\mathbb N$, $1$ with a copy of the negative integers, and replace each point other than $0$ and $1$ with a copy of $\mathbb Z$". The draft in my mind is usually nicer than whatever ends up on the page.

Comment: @Andres: Yes, that is a common effect of paper on mathematics.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It gets worse with age. And children.

Answer (score 1):

Let our set be $A\cup B\cup C$, where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are pairwise disjoint sets. Let $A$ be order-isomorphic to the set of non-negative integers with the usual order, $B$ order-isomorphic to the set of integers under the usual order, and $C$ order-isomorphic to the negative integers under the usual order. Declare every element of $A$ less than any element of $B$ or $C$, and every element of $B$ less than every element of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward order that satisfies the conditions is $\omega+\omega^*$ (where $\omega^*$ is the standard well-ordering on $\mathbb{N}$ 'backwards').  Equivalently, take $\mathbb{Z}$ and say that every negative number is *greater than* every positive (or zero) number, and that negative and positive numbers are 'internally' ordered as they are normally.  Then $-1$ is the largest element, $0$ is the smallest, and it's relatively easy to see that all of your other conditions are satisfied.  This order has a nice mental image of starting at zero, walking off to infinity, 'wrapping around', and walking back in from negative-infinity: $0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, -3, -2, -1$.  Note that the conditions you've given don't force a well-ordering, because they don't include the 'well' portion, that there be no infinite descending chains.

(Postscript: you should be able to show that any *well*-ordering which satisfies all of your conditions is finite.  I'll leave it up to you to figure out why this doesn't actually contradict what your instructor said...)

Comment: The postscript is fine. No need for the slightly-less confidence.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo It's 'intuitively' obvious but my knowledge of non-standard models isn't as good as it could be, so I wasn't certain that there wasn't a non-standard model where it didn't hold.  I've added some confidence to the postscript; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\ :\ n\ge 3\right\} \cup \left\{1-\frac{1}{n}\ :\ n\ge 3\right\}$? You did not state that the upper or lower bounds had to be in the set.

Comment: The question is about abstract ordered sets. Upper and lower bounds are concepts that only make sense in reference to elements of the set. Otherwise, any set would work, as you can always add bounds to it.